# How to Create this type of view in IOS? (See in Image)

Tags: ios, objective-c, checkbox, progress-bar, pageviews

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any Library of IOS then suggest me.. thank u

Comment: What do you want? A progress bar in navigation controller, CheckBoxes or radio button. Please specify in your description.

Comment: Full page view screen. If i select split ac then view push in second screen , same type of this scrren

Comment: @Vishal16 i want full page view like above screesnshot. In ios.

Comment: This is a customise thing.You should design it and search code to set layers. Also, for ProgressBar you will get code, for table you need to design custom cell, for checkBox you can use Background images to button & for RadioButton you need to set layers to your button.

Comment: @chaaruu , you have any idea about ProgressBar in navigation bar? any library?

Comment: Why you are searching for library? You can create your own. Hide NavigationBar and use UIView instead. Now design that view as per your requirements. Mostly, We are doing the same thing when we need custom NavigationBar. On NavigationBar you can only set background image and BarButtons.

Comment: You don't need add any complications in simple designs. You start creating it will work properly.. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Here, no one is free to create view as you need, also you are not getting from comments and answers so I think you are very beginner, learn iOS and do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use any third party library for this :-

1. Navigation bar

   1.1 Use that arrow for back button by setting leftbarbuttonitem

   1.2 For Progress Bar and progress label you can design separate view and can add it as title view (self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView)
2. For question and answer, you can use table view

   2.1 Question:- Use table header or section header

   2.2 Answer:- Use Table view cell with check box or radio button 
     Use single selection logic for radio button and multi selection for check box
3. Done Button

   Use table footer to show done button

Comment: nicely explained.

Answer (score -1):

Hiii,

[image]

Use StoryBoard place a ViewController and embed in navigation controller then provide a storyboard id to navigation controller and then get that same viewController on next button clicked.

```
UINavigationController *navVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewController"];
YourViewController *yourVC = navVC.topViewController;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourVC animated:true];
```

Now you can get same ViewController every time. Provide some instance variable which loads specific data for presentation.

OR

Also, you can directly access a view controller if it's already embedded in Navigation Controller like

```
YourViewController *yourVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewController"];
```

open identity inspector and provide storyboard id directly and push this viewController.

Comment: if i want to go back then whats to do?

Comment: Simply call this  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: then i goes back in main menu... i f i check one box then do next, , after then i click on back, now how to get back?

Comment: Again, call pushViewController method of navigationController.

Comment: Okay. If it's working fine can you please accept the Answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153934/discussion-between-mr-bond-and-vishal16).